# Get Data Quarterly in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using SQLServer2008.

```
SELECT  Amount ,
        OpportunityCloseDate
FROM    dbo.OpportunityMaster AS om
```

and output is:

```
Amount      OpportunityCloseDate
------------------------------------
25458.00    2012-07-02 00:00:00.000
54555.00    2012-08-16 00:00:00.000
2154.00     2012-08-21 00:00:00.000
123458.00   2013-08-31 00:00:00.000
54546.00    2013-08-28 00:00:00.000
1235.00     2013-08-22 00:00:00.000
56454.00    2013-08-22 00:00:00.000
156.00      2013-09-13 00:00:00.000
34534.00    2013-09-04 00:00:00.000
34355.00    2013-09-02 00:00:00.000
76568.00    2013-09-01 00:00:00.000
235646.00   2013-09-10 00:00:00.000
54465.00    2013-09-18 00:00:00.000
244254.00   2013-12-19 00:00:00.000
```

Expected Output :

```
Amount      Quarter
------------------
82167.00    Q1
671417.00   Q2
244254.00   Q3
```

In my database Year starts from 1st April. 
I want to get this data quarterly. I dont know much about quarter..Thanks for help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to sum the data for each quarter:

```
;With Totals as (

    SELECT  SUM(Amount) as Total,
            DATEADD(quarter,DATEDIFF(quarter,0,OpportunityCloseDate),0) as RoundQuarter
    FROM    dbo.OpportunityMaster AS om
    GROUP BY
            DATEADD(quarter,DATEDIFF(quarter,0,OpportunityCloseDate),0)
)
select
    Total,
    DATEPART(year,RoundQuarter) -
       CASE WHEN DATEPART(quarter,RoundQuarter) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as FinancialYear,
    CASE WHEN DATEPART(quarter,RoundQuarter) = 1 THEN 4
       ELSE DATEPART(quarter,RoundQuarter) - 1 END as FinancialQuarter
from
    Totals
```

[`DATEADD`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)

This works by working out the (whole number) number of quarters that have occurred since `1900-01-01`<sup>1</sup>, and then by adding that same number of quarters on to `1900-01-01`. This has the effect of rounding each date down to the 1st day in each quarter.

<sup>1</sup>0 when converted to a `datetime` is treated as `1900-01-01`.

Comment: @Prashant16 - your update still doesn't make it clear whether you want the sum, the average, the min, the max, because your example output doesn't seem to bear an obvious relation to the example input. At the moment, the second column from my query will be one of `2012-07-01`, `2013-07-01` or `2013-10-01` (i.e. the first date in each quarter) - it could be changed to just include the quarter number, but since you have data from a mix of years, I'm not sure that that would be sensible.

Comment: I have seen that in sql server 1st quarter starts from 1st January but in my application i have to start 1st quarter from 1st April. I want to sum of amount with quarter number, not date. And also i want to get data from last 4 quarters.

Comment: @Prashant16 - I've updated it to try to get formatting closer to what you want, I think. It's important, when solving this sort of problem, to clearly distinguish between core parts of the calculation (i.e. finding which quarter each value belongs to, and computing the sum) from formatting concerns (whether January, April, July or October is "quarter 1")

Comment: Can you write query that give me last date of current quarter?

Comment: @Prashant16 - ah, see, this is now where we get sneaky with `DATEADD` and `DATEDIFF` - The expression `DATEADD(quarter,DATEDIFF(quarter,'19000101',GETDATE()),'19000331')` will return the last date of the current quarter. Just replace `GETDATE()` with any other date value to find the last date relating to that date's quarter. Leave the `19000101` and `19000331` constants fixed.